# initialize an array of structs with function pointers in them C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, function-pointers

I am trying to initialize an array of structs. the structs have function pointers in them and are defined as such:

```
typedef struct{
      char str[512];
      char *fptr;
} infosection;
```

then I try to make an array:

```
infosection section[] = {
      ("Software", *SoftwarePtr),
      ("Hardware", *HardwarePtr),
 }
```

I defined the function pointers using a simple tutorial.
Function Software returns an int

```
int (*SoftwarePtr)()=NULL;
SoftwarePtr = &Software;
```

My question is about the warnings I get upon compiling.

> Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

The warning references the lines in the section array.

So I have two doubts:

1. Am I misusing the */&/neither for the pointer?I have tried combinations of each and i still seem to get the same warning.I am aware of the meaning of each, just unsure how they apply in this particular instance.
2. Can I declare an instance of the `infosection struct` in an array as i do here?I have seen many examples where people declare their `array of struct` in a `for loop`,
   However my final product requires a long list of structs to be contained in that array.I would like to make my code `portable` such that people can `add structs` ( strings which correspond with functions to point to) in an easy list-like fashion as seen about.
   Is this the only way to declare an instance of the array

   ```
     infosection section[];
     section[0].str="software";
     section[0].fptr=SoftwarePtr;
   ```

Just to clarify, i have done quite a bit of research on `structs`, `array of structs`, and `function pointers`. It just seems that the combination of the 3 is causing trouble.

Comment: I thought function pointers were void *().

Comment: @Jim I read here: http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi that function pointer's need to be declared with the return type of the function they point to...

Comment: `char *fptr;` This is not a function pointer and conversions between `char*` and a function pointer are not well-defined

Comment: Anyway, a better question might be: which crap compiler allowed all of these errors to slip through? Please don't tell me you are using Turbo C...

Comment: That was GCC my friend

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One**

One mistake I an find, in structure declaration of function pointer is incorrect:

```
typedef struct{
      char str[512];
      int (*fptr)();  // not char* fptr
} infosection;
```

**Two**

declaration:

```
infosection section[] = {
      ("Software", *SoftwarePtr),
      ("Hardware", *HardwarePtr),
 }
```

Should be:

```
infosection section[] = {
      {"Software", SoftwarePtr},
      {"Hardware", HardwarePtr}
 }
```

Remove `*`. and replace inner `(` `)` with  `{` `}`.

**three**:

```
infosection section[];
section[0].str="software"; // compiler error
section[0].fptr=SoftwarePtr;
```

Is wrong you can't assign string in this way. you need to use `strcpy()` as follows;

```
strcpy(section[0].str, "software");
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the trailing comma: some coding styles even favour it as it makes each row consistent. Array initialization lists have always allowed to have trailing commas on the last row.

Answer (score 2):

The struct member is currently a char*, change to the correct pointer type for your function signature.

```
typedef struct{
  char str[512];
  int (*fptr)();
} infosection;
```

* dereference the pointer, read *foo as "what foo points at".
You want to set the struct member to the actual pointer, also use bracets instead of paranthesis.

```
infosection section[] = {
  {"Software", SoftwarePtr},
  {"Hardware", HardwarePtr}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

been a while since i was playin around with pointers but maybe a constructor would help?

```
struct infosection{
      char str[512];
      char *fptr;
      infosection(char* strN, char* fptrN): str(strN), fptr(fptrN) {}
};

infosection[] isxn = { new infosection(&str1,fptr1), 
               new infosection(&str2,fptr2)},
               ... };
```

my apologies...where c stops and c++ begins has become blurred in my mind, i have seen a workaround for c that looks like this (but not exactly, im sure some of the pointer stuff is mixed up but this was the idea)

```
struct infosection{
  char str[512];
  char *fptr;
};

infosection* myIS (char *strN, char *fptrN) {
  infosection i = new infosection();
  i.str = &strN;
  i.fptr = fptrN;
  return *i;
}

//infosection* newInfoSection = myIS(myStrPtr,myFptr);
```

Comment: Constuctors are a part of C++ though, and wont work in this senario =)